# Create a tuple from a variable and a list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a variable `s` which is a string, and a list of ints called `l`. What is the quickest way to add `s` to the front of `l` and convert the end result of that `concatenation` into a tuple?

This is working for me:

```
l.insert(0, s)
t = tuple(l)
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Concatenate them:

```
t = (s,) + tuple(l)
```

Insertion in front of the list would alter the list itself, and requires looping over the whole list twice (once for insertion, moving the rest of the list up 1 step, once for creating the tuple).

Answer (score 1):

Construct result with generator expression that loops through the list once and requires no final concatenation:

```
t = tuple(l[i] if i > -1 else s for i in xrange(-1, len(l)))
```